# In Reporting services, how do I add an image from a string or cell in the table?

Tags: image, reporting-services

What I'm trying to do is this: I have a string with the full path to the image. I tried to add an external image to my report and set the image source to my string. but every time I load the report, it doesn't load the image. How do I do this, or is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an External image, the image source needs to be a URL for the image. Reporting Services will try to get the image using anonymous access.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220527.aspx

Comment: is there a way for the image source to be from a folderpath ( I.E. C:\Images\ImageName.jpg)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it figured out. What I did was in the image properties, in the General Tab, I selected the image source as External, I then created a report parameter Called "@ImageURL", and selected it in the "Use this image:". 
On the form I added this line of code:
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New Parameter("ImageURL", string.concat("file:\","C:\ImagesFolder\ImageName.jpg")))
this brings up the image correctly.